# Table code working on separate file but not in main

Tags: nicematrix

Hello so I am working on an assignment and I have created a table in a file called table.tex that looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|X|X|X[2]|}[hlines]
     \textbf{Attribute} & \textbf{Possible Values} & \textbf{Description}  \\
 
 Class  & DIE,ALIVE  & Whether patient survived disease or not  \\
 AGE  & 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80  & Age of patient   \\
 SEX  & male, female  & Binary gender of patient   \\
 ANTIVIRALS  & no, yes  & Whether patient was given steroids    \\
 FATIGUE  & no, yes  & Whether patient presented fatigue as a symptom    \\
 MALAISE  & no, yes  & Whether a patient presented malaise as a symptom    \\
 ANOREXIA  & no, yes  & Whether patient suffered from anorexia when they got hepatitis   \\
 LIVER BIG  & no, yes  & Whether the size of the liver of the patient is big   \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

So, this code is working in a separate .tex file, but when I try to copy and paste it in my main.tex  I recieve the following error:
**Fatal Package nicematrix Error: The column type '2' in your environment**
I really do not understand why this is the case since the code is working on the separate file. Can someone help me?

I have also thought about printing this in the separate file and adding it to the main from there but I am not sure I am doing this correctly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should be able to show an example that makes the error. start from a copy of your main document and delete everything except the table, and any packages not needed to show the error

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is hard to tell what causes the problem, since we don't know the contents of the file `main.tex`. If you use the preamble of `main.tex` and just place as contents the above `NiceTabular`, would this work? If yes, I fear you have to take a step-by-step approach by deleting some lines in `main.tex`, recompile, and this way identify where the problem may be ... Or go the other way around: take the above MWE and stepwise add the stuff from your `main.tex` until the problem comes up.